# Proper way to configure ~/.Xsession with a standalone window manager to gracefully end a session

Tags: linux, session, openbox

I'm using `xdm` and my `~/.Xsession` looks like this:

```
# <initialization stuff here>

exec openbox
```

It works, but I've noticed that when I log out `Openbox` doesn't gracefully kill all the applications. In particular `Google Chrome` complains about that.

How can I make sure to wait for all processes to exit (just like others configurations: Gnome, KDE, Windows ...)?

The only (**ugly**) solution that I've found involves `sleep` and `kill` into `~/.Xsession`.

Answer (score 1):

You need a session manager to gracefully kill the applications.  `openbox-session` may do what you want.  The documents explicitly say it doesn't do the saving session part, but it may do the gracefully kill part.  `openbox-gnome-session` or `openbox-kde-session` will let you use the respective session managers while using openbox as your window manager.

Comment: Tried that, no way, same behavior. What else can I use as session manager? I can't see many (stand-alone) choices.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I solved, I edited `~/.Xsession` this way:

```
# <initialization stuff here>

openbox-session &
WM_PID=$!

sleep 0.5 # time needed to start openbox

# <autostart applications here>

wait $WM_PID

for i in `ps -u $USER -o pid= | grep -v $$` ; do
    kill $i
done

sleep 1 # grace time
```

I can't find anything better by now. Maybe I should use a session manager but I don't know which one fits my case.